# I needed help to convert below R dataframe

Tags: r, transpose

I needed help to convert below R dataframe. Can anyone can help me to do it?
I tried

df:

```
YRMONTH  | ABC | BCD | CDA | ING
---------------------------------
Jan-2021 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123
FEB-2021 | 124 | 124 | 0   | 124
MAR-2021 | 125 | 125 | 125 | 125
APR-2021 | 126 | 126 | 126 | 0
```

Output:

```
YRMONTH | Jan-2021 | FEB-2021 | MAR-2021 | APR-2021 ...
---------------------------------------------------
ABC     | 123      | 124      | 125      | 126 
BCD     | 123      | 124      | 125      | 126
CDA     | 123      | 0        | 125      | 126
ING     | 123      | 124      | 125      | 0
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: get started by just applying `t()` to your original data frame. you might need to move the rownames to a column and convert back to a data frame (`t()` might turn your data into a matrix), but all the info should be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use [`data.table::transpose`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/transpose)

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'YRMONTH', keep.names = 'YRMONTH')
```

-output

```
   YRMONTH Jan-2021 FEB-2021 MAR-2021 APR-2021
1     ABC      123      124      125      126
2     BCD      123      124      125      126
3     CDA      123        0      125      126
4     ING      123      124      125        0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(YRMONTH = c("Jan-2021", "FEB-2021", "MAR-2021", 
"APR-2021"), ABC = 123:126, BCD = 123:126, CDA = c(123L, 0L, 
125L, 126L), ING = c(123L, 124L, 125L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```